# Access a on-premise Bitbucket Server from Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I try to make this question as simple as possible...

I have an internal Bitbucket server in my data center, with a record in our local DNS (for example: bitbucket.mycompany.internal).

I set up a pipeline in Azure DevOps using the Other git option (not Bitbucket Cloud).

But I get this error message when I run the pipeline:

`[error] Git retrieval failed with exit code: 128`

I saw that the problem comes from Azure DevOps cannot resolve the FQDN of my local Bitbucket.

How can I configure Azure DevOps so that it can resolve my internal Bitbucket FQDN mame that is on my data center.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a self-hosted agent which is running in your own datacenter. That way the Agent uses your internal DNS to resolve the host.

[You can link Azure DevOps over Azure ExpressRoute in case you want the agent to talk over a secured connection](https://www.dailyhostnews.com/expressroute-for-azure-devops-and-new-availability-zones#:%7E:text=ExpressRoute%20is%20available%20for%20all%20Azure%20DevOps%20services,,Studio%20Subscriber%20Portal,%20Visual%20Studio%20Subscriptions%20Administration%20Portal.). But that can't be used to link the Hosted agents to your local agents.